# input with data validation doesn't trigger change event

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation

```
$(function() {
    $("#collapseNew div[data-role=contractContainer] .table-row-b > .row input").change(function () {
        //find if is need a new line
        var $this = $(this);
        var lineContainer = $this.closest("div.row");
        if (typeof(lineContainer.data().requestLine) === "undefined") {
            addRow($this, function() {
                lineContainer.data("requestLine", true);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

this simple jquery code never trigger in my page is possible is related to those inputs have validations with jquery.validate

how can I get change event without pressing of validation

FYI: $("#collapseNew div[data-role=contractContainer] .table-row-b > .row input") is valid and contain the inputs in question

In fact, validation related with those input work find. so, I guess unobtrusive-validation is subscribed to the change event but in some way it override my subscriptions

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure `"#collapseNew div[data-role=contractContainer] .table-row-b > .row input"` matches any elements?

Comment: the selector, in fact, match the 4 elements that I want to, I can see it in browser console where $("#collapseNew div[data-role=contractContainer] .table-row-b > .row input").length == 4

Comment: I put a breakpoint  in line 4 var $this= $(this); and it never go throught

Comment: The question contains no code related to the jQuery Validation plugin.